# c# compare mysql current result with the next one in line

Tags: c#, mysql, while-loop, resultset

To iterate through my result set, a lists of lists, I'm currently using:

```
    foreach (IELog ieLog in emailAttach)
    {
        logAttachment += ieLog.FirstName + "," + ieLog.LastName +
             "," + ieLog.Building + "," + ieLog.Room + "," + ieLog.Ingresstime + "," 
             + ieLog.Egresstime + "\n";
     }
```

I would like to compare ieLog.FirstName with the next one in line and image it would work something like this, just my syntax is wrong.

```
n = 0;
while (emailAttach.FirstName [n] == emailAttach.FirstName[n++] {
     do something;
    }
```

The result set looks like:

Person    | Login | Logout

York Hunt  intime outtime

York Hunt  intime outtime

York Hunt  intime outtime

York Hunt  intime outtime

Mike Hunt  intime outtime

Mike Hunt  intime outtime

Mike Hunt  intime outtime

Mike Hunt  intime outtime

and I'm aiming for just the name once

York Hunt  intime outtime

```
       intime outtime

       intime outtime 

       intime outtime
```

Mike Hunt  intime outtime

```
       intime outtime 

       intime outtime 

       intime outtime
```

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to get the `FirstName` property of the n<sup>th</sup> item inside `emailAttach`.

In other words, `emailAttach[n].FirstName`.

Also, you need to change `n++` to `++n`.

Comment: I'm stumped, this one answers specifically what i asked, but Jon Skeets may get the check.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have LINQ available to you (at least at the client) you should just use `source.GroupBy(x => x.FirstName)` to group entries for the same name together.

Comment: I was thinking the exact same thing, using LINQ you could easily accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in MySQL instead.
http://www.mysqlfaqs.net/mysql-faqs/SQL-Statements/Select-Statement/How-does-DISTINCT-work-in-MySQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName, LastName, Building, Room, Ingresstime, Egresstime FROM table
```

Comment: This would be really cool, but I want the data in the rows with a duplicate name just not the name.  Like if you had ad db of student grades and you want the student and all there grades line by line, but only one entry of the student.